# execute two db query in which one query result pass as input to another query asynchronous node js

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda

```
  //global array to store dynamodb query result 
  var store = [];

  //function that  to retrive socket data based on user email id as a hash key and give json to pass into query by taking email as input
  var getSocketParams = (email) => {
    return {
        TableName: "socketSockets",
        KeyConditionExpression: "user_id = :em",
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
            ":em": email
        }
    };
 }
 //query 1 which retrive all sockets details from respective table 
 var q1 = (callback) => {
     retrivalDetail(getSocketParams(em), function(err, res) {
         if (err) callback(err, null);
         callback(null, res);
     });
 };

 //query 2 take input as a result of query 1 response and second a callback 
 var q2 = (res, callback) => {
     //here i made some logic to check callback is not executed until all items in query 1 response executed and that respective data fetched from respective table if have any 
     var ctr = 0;
     res.Items.forEach(function(d) {
         var payload_params_l = {
             TableName: "socketPayload",
             KeyConditionExpression: "#mac = :mac",
             ExpressionAttributeNames: {
                 "#mac": "mac"
             },
             ExpressionAttributeValues: {
                 ":mac": d.socket_id
             },
             ScanIndexForward: false,
             Limit: 1
         };
         retrivalDetail(payload_params_l, function(err, res) {
             if (err) callback(err, null);
             store.push(res);
             ctr++;                                
             if (ctr === Object.keys(res.Items).length) {
                 callback(null, store);
             }
         });
     });
 };
 //my function call to excute query 1 and query 2 here problem is due to asynchronous nature of node js i guess  before getting query 1 result completely query2 will be start executing so i place q2 inside q1 callback here how can i retrive all data from q2 inside loop and pass all data after finishing loop to q2 callback 
 function call() {
     q1(function(err, res) {
         if (err) done(err, null);
         q2(res, function(err, res) {
             if (err) done(err, null);
             //final function done which gives response to API request done(error ,response)
             done(null, res);
         });
     });
 };
 call();
```

Here the issue i am facing is  due to asynchronous nature of event loop of node js i guess before getting query 1 result completely query2 will be start executing so i place q2 inside q1 callback here i want better suggestion to improve this code that how can i retrive all data from q2 inside loop and pass all data after finishing loop to q2 callback

i am newbie to use async package in node js if possible using async module how it would be any help regarding this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function call() it's okey , you can use async.waterfall if you want https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#waterfall , but for the function q2 it is much more better to use async.forEachOf function https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#eachOf

```
 //global array to store dynamodb query result 
  var store = [];

  //function that  to retrive socket data based on user email id as a hash key and give json to pass into query by taking email as input
  var getSocketParams = (email) => {
    return {
        TableName: "socketSockets",
        KeyConditionExpression: "user_id = :em",
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
            ":em": email
        }
    };
 }
 //query 1 which retrive all sockets details from respective table 
 var q1 = (callback) => {
     retrivalDetail(getSocketParams(em), function(err, res) {
         if (err) callback(err, null);
         callback(null, res);
     });
 };

 var q2 = (res, callback) => {

  async.forEachOf(res.Item, function (d, index, done) {

     var payload_params_l = {
             TableName: "socketPayload",
             KeyConditionExpression: "#mac = :mac",
             ExpressionAttributeNames: {
                 "#mac": "mac"
             },
             ExpressionAttributeValues: {
                 ":mac": d.socket_id
             },
             ScanIndexForward: false,
             Limit: 1
         };
         retrivalDetail(payload_params_l, function(err, res) {
             if (err) {
                done(err, null);
             } else {
                store.push(res);
                done(null);
             }
         });
  }, 
    function (error) {
        // la fin du traitement de tous les records
        if (error)  callback(error, null)
        else callback(null, store);
    });
 }



 //my function call to excute query 1 and query 2 here problem is due to asynchronous nature of node js i guess  before getting query 1 result completely query2 will be start executing 
 //so i place q2 inside q1 callback here how can i retrive all data from q2 inside loop and pass all data after finishing loop to q2 callback 
 function call() {
     q1(function(err, res) {
         if (err) done(err, null);
         q2(res, function(err, res) {
             if (err) done(err, null);
             //final function done which gives response to API request done(error ,response)
             done(null, res);
         });
     });
 };
```

Comment: Thank You @yMag.......as i said earlier i am not using async ever before that grt to have method forEachOf in async to resolve.....here another sample code i like to share with and its working  have look into this